# react-native-navigation v2: Get current route

Tags: javascript, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I want to forbid BackButton closing app when in the root of the navigator.
How can I detect current route?

Or maybe there is builtin react-native-navigation method to work with backbutton?

Answer (score 1):

Getting current Route

```
this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
```

Handle Back button

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
    //Handle ur back functionality here.
}
```

Comment: this is for react-native-navigation OR react-navigation?

Comment: @rendom react-navigation

Comment: @rendom for react-native-navigation  try this.props.navigator.screenIsCurrentlyVisible()

Comment: is this available in version 2?